# Unsure how to structure SQL data warehouse query

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

Data warehousing is a very new concept to me. I understand the fundamentals and i am trying to create an DW based on a star schema. The problem is how to structure a query in order to get back the required information - i am not sure how exactly to do this. SQL was never my strong point (hence why i am practicing, its been along time since i had to use SQL). I would like to return the profits for all locations in the years 2014 and 2015. Does anyone have any pointers of how to structure my query?

```
 insert into profitable_county(depot_location,journey_cost, journey_dates, time_weekStart, time_weekEnd, year_, total_2014, total_2015)
 select DepotLocation,Cost,journeyDate,WeekStart,WeekEnd,year,Cost,Cost
 from depot, journeys, time;


 select depot_location, total_2014, total_2015
 from profitable_county 
 where time_weekStart=51;
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical DWH architecture would use details tables and aggregation tables. That is, for instance, in your case the details table such as depot or journeys would contain detailed information (for ex: daily information about journeys cost for each depot).

Then, depending on your needs, you need to have a table where you can retrieve more quickly data if you want to know the costs per year. So, instead of fetching through thousands of rows in your details table, you prepare an already calculated information in an aggregation table that would have for example weekly profils (that is a column of week of year, a column for depot, a column for cost ...).

In the queries I am seeing, it's quite hard to tell or answer your question. However, generally, a data warehouse SQL scripts would have a "generic" format. Let's take a case of company that has different point of sales and wants to know the sales for each point of sales.

The source information it has is the orders per customers. 
Details table would be the first source of information (let's say, information you get from receipt and cash registers connected to your ERPs then to your DWH).

To insert data in there, a typical SQL statement would be :

```
  INSERT INTO Customer_Orders_History
  SELECT DATE_ID,
  Customer_ID,
  Order_ID,
  Order_Value,
  Point_of_sale
  FROM ERP_DB.Some_Table A
  LEFT JOIN ERP_DB.Some_Table2 B ON A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
```

Now,
we move to aggregation where its more easy to know the sales for each point of sale

```
  INSERT INTO Customer_Orders_History_Aggregation
  SELECT DATE_ID,
  Point_Of_Sale,
  SUM(Order_Value)

  FROM Customer_Orders_History
  GROUP BY DATE_ID,
  Point_Of_Sale
```

So, in this last aggregation table, knowing the amount of sales per each point of sale is much more easier because we would have to look up for what you want in fewer rows.

But, there's no one or set of rules to do a SQL statement for DWH if a thorough description of your tables and the links between them are not provided.

EDIT:
And one important thing, in data warehouse SQL statement, when it is about to insert, remember that these scripts are generally run by a data integration tool and that it is run on a frequent basis (daily, monthly...) and in an automatic way. So, declaring dates as variables (ex:$DATE_ID) is a must unless you are manually doing ETL :D

Hope I am of help ;)